# How to show records that match specific conditions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please indicate how to correct this query to show records with Continente= Europe and PBI ≥ 1.4?

```
db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').aggregate([{$match:{Continente:{$eq:"Europa"}}, {PBI:{$gt:"1.4"}})
```

This error is appearing currently:

> Error: Line 1: Unexpected token {

And this is the database in Robo 3T/MongoDB:
[MongoDB Collection and DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANbIE.png)

Thanks to Vijay Rajpurohit for his help in correcting the query.
The final query is:
db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').aggregate([{$match:{"Continente":"Europa","PIB":{$gte:"1.4"}}}])

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there just three things need to be fixed:

1. brackets were not closed
2. You are searching for the continent with wrong spelling `"Continente":{$eq:"Europa"}`
3. you want `"PBI" ≥ 1.4`, So use `$gte` instead of `$gt`

The rest is correct.

```
db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      "Continente":"Europe",
      "PBI":{
        $gte:"1.4"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you Vijay... I included the final query in the original post.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)